# Close allactivities in Android app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app for sending sms. It consists of several "cascading" activities - one for writing text, next for choosing number and next for confirming before sending. After sending the message I want that all activities get closed. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start all the Activities with `startActivityForResult` you can chain the `finish` calls in `onActivityResult`: basically make the final Activity call `finish` after setting a specific result code, and each earlier activity checks for that result code and if its there does the same thing. They'll all close up cleanly and you should be all set.

Answer (score 2):

You will find no well-written Android apps that have this behavior.

After sending the message, you are welcome to send them back to your main activity using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, which will remove all intervening activities between the current one and the main activity, using something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Well my app has to behave that way so user don't get drowned in too complex interface :) Instead of using "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP", can i use static list of "visited" activities and then close acording to list?

Comment: I have to agree with guest86 here. You should sort out the design of your UI, instead of trying to play tricks like this.

Comment: @Philip Sheard: You mean besides the fact that "tricks like" having a home affordance that returns the user to the main activity is what Google recommends? Now, normally, that would be accomplished by explicit user request (e.g., clicking an icon in an action bar). But returning the user to a main activity is significantly superior to the app vanishing in a puff of virtual smoke.